# Coin Toss Game with differential probability

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-probability, game-theory

This problem is from QuantGuide(namely Tricky Bob 1):
Bob proposes a game where Alice and Bob are each given a coin. Each is allowed decide the probability of heads for their coin. Afterwards, they both flip their coins. If it comes up HH, Alice gives Bob 6 dollar. If it comes up TT, Alice gives Bob 4dolla. Otherwise, Bob gives Alice 5 dollar. However, Alice must tell Bob the success probability $p_1$ ​ they have chosen before Bob decides his $p_2$. The interval of values for $p_1$​ such that regardless of what Bob selects, Bob has non-positive expected value on the game is in the form [a,b], where a and b are rational numbers.
My Approach:
The expectation value  equation will be:
\begin{equation}
6p_1p_2+4(1-p_1)(1-p_2)-5p1(1-p_2)-5p2(1-p_1)=20p_1p_2-9(p_1+p_2)+4 \le 0
\end{equation}. Hence the conditions will be :
\begin{equation}
p_1 \le \frac{9p_2-4}{20p_2-9}
\end{equation}
In the range from 0 to 1 for $p_2$ it assumes a negative value as well as a value greater than 1. Hence according to me, there can't be any value for $p_1$ such that Bob will get a non-positive expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the expected value is correct.  However, I think you've misinterpreted the nature of the question.  Let
$$E(p_1, p_2) = 20 p_1 p_2 - 9 (p_1 + p_2) + 4 = 20 \left( p_1 - \frac{9}{20} \right)\left(p_2 - \frac{9}{20}\right) - \frac{1}{20}.$$
be the expected value.  The question is asking, for what $p_1 \in [0,1]$ is is true that $E(p_1, p_2) \le 0$ for all $p_2 \in [0,1]$?  Well, it's clear that $E(9/20, p_2) = -1/20 \le 0$ no matter what choice of $p_2$ we take.  So this immediately demonstrates that there is at least one choice of $p_1$ that meets the problem's criteria.

Moreover, we can intuitively see that if $p_1$ is "sufficiently close" to $9/20$, that we could get a non-positive expectation for any choice of $p_2$.  This suggests letting $a = p_1 - 9/20$ and $b = p_2 - 9/20$, hence
$$E(p_1, p_2) \propto ab - \frac{1}{400}.$$  And now it becomes very clear that if
$$b \le \frac{1}{400 a}$$
if $a > 0$, or if
$$b \ge \frac{1}{400 a}$$ if $a < 0$, then $E(p_1, p_2) \le 0$.  What we need to do is find out what value(s) of $a$ exist such that the respective inequality is true for all permissible $b$.  In other words, if $a > 0$, we require
$$p_2 - \frac{9}{20} = b \le \frac{1}{400a}$$
or $$\frac{1}{400(p_1 - 9/20)} + \frac{9}{20} \ge 1, \quad \text{and} \quad p_1 > 9/20.$$  This implies
$$\frac{9}{20} < p_1 \le \frac{5}{11}.$$
Similarly, if $a < 0$, we require that $1/(400a) \le 0$, or
$$\frac{1}{400(p_1 - 9/20)} + \frac{9}{20} \le 0, \quad \text{and} \quad p_1 < 9/20.$$  This implies
$$\frac{4}{9} \le p_1 < \frac{9}{20}.$$
Putting all of this together, we find that whenever
$$\frac{4}{9} \le p_1 \le \frac{5}{11},$$
then $E(p_1, p_2) \le 0$ for any choice of $p_2 \in [0,1]$.